# Does flutter has any equivalent widget as android spinner?

Tags: flutter

I know there is DropDown Button but how dropdown button work is it show content in popup style and i want to implement autocomplete textfield and want to interact with textfield while suggestion come under textfield.

Comment: You can use the TextField's controller to update the dropdown buttons' list every time the text changes in the TextField.

Comment: I mean when dropdown show it hide the text field and all i want is show dropdown exactly below the text field and change content while text change like spinner view does in android. i have tired using overlay but then i had to manually  dismiss overlay

Comment: If you want it to be below the TextField then the TextField and the DropDownButton should go in a Column widget

Answer (score 0):

There is a package available for this that you can use and it works very nicely. 
You can also fetch the suggestions list from API.

Here is the link

https://github.com/jebright/flutter_typeahead_plugin